# How to Find out Site definition being used by a Site

Tags: 2007, development, site-template, site, site-definition

I always struggle to find out that how to know what site definition or site template a "Web" or a "Site" is using. We do have a lot of custom site definitions and site templates, we are using in our portal, so If there is any freeware tool or way to find out, would be great.

We keep records of Site Templates in Database, but I want to know if there is any way, I find it out using a C# script or simply any app.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following code in your C# Console Application and you'll get the listing all your sub-sites with their respective site definitions

```
using (SPSite ospSite = new SPSite("http://server/"))
{
    SPWebCollection webs = ospSite.AllWebs;
    foreach (SPWeb web in webs)
    {

       try
       {
          string template = web.WebTemplate;
          Console.WriteLine(web.Url.ToString() + " : " template.ToString());
       }
       finally {web.Dispose();}
    }

 }
```

Comment: Cheers brother done it, I was wondering if you have any twitter account or LinkedIn , i can follow you :)

Comment: As I say it, follow me at your own risk ;) https://twitter.com/#!/falaky

Answer (score 1):

Use [SPWeb.WebTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplate.aspx) property.